# store and retrieve assigned index of svg elements

Tags: d3.js

Can you please tell me how can I store index and get it if clicked on the drawn elements? In my case when an event is received a glyph is drawn. I just want to assign a no or index [0, 1, 2, ...] to each glyph. Later on when a glyph is clicked, I just want to retrieve that assigned no.. A small example is created here, dataset is not quite same in my case. Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> Icon </title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/d3/d3.v3.js"></script>
</head>


<body>

<p id="drawing">

    <script>

        // data is not same as here, just to explain the requirement created it.
        var incomingData = [40, 50, 80, 72];
        var svg = d3.select("#drawing")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("height", 200)
                .attr("width", 200)
                .attr("transform", "translate(20, 20)");

        for(var i = 0; i < incomingData.length; ++i) {
            svg.append("circle")
                    .attr("cx", 10 + incomingData[i])
                    .attr("cy", 10)
                    .attr("r", 5)
                    .style("fill", "grey")
                    .on("mouseover", function () {
                        d3.select(this)
                                .style("fill", "orange");
                    })
                    .on("mouseout", function () {
                        d3.select(this)
                                .style("fill", "gray");
                    })
                    .on("click", function() {
                        alert("Index= .");

                    });

        }

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a special reason you are not binding the data in the `d3`-way? I would suggest something like:

```
    svg.selectAll('circle').data(incomingData).enter().append("circle")
        .attr("cx", function(d) {
            return 10 + d;
        })
        .attr("cy", 10)
        .attr("r", 5)
        .style("fill", "grey")
        .on("mouseover", function() {
            d3.select(this)
                    .style("fill", "orange");
        })
        .on("mouseout", function() {
            d3.select(this)
                    .style("fill", "gray");
        })
        .on("click", function(d, i) {
            alert("Index= " + i);

        });
```

This way, you bind the `incomingData` using `data`, so each element has an `index`, see e.g. here: http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/binding-data

Comment: The incoming data is quite different. My example code is very bad, sorry. Is there a way to assign a number to a element, that i can retrieve when clicked?

Comment: well, where does that number come from in your example? Is it provided by the data? If so, maybe you want to add a "slightly better" example of the data? You can pass any number of data objects to the "circle producing function" and assign them accordingly.

Comment: The numbers are coming from events generated externally. I am looking for a way to assign or bind a number to the glyph (here circle) and retrieve it when clicked.

Comment: The solution I provided binds the data to the cirlce, thus you can retrieve it as presented, e.g. using another alert: `alert("Index= " + i + " data: " + d);` (by the way: I recommend using `console.log` over alert :) ). As you can see, I am already using the bound data to determine `cx` of the `cirlce`.

Comment: Thank a lot for the answer. My question was not clear, sorry. I got solution to my requirement - store in a index attribute and later I retrieve it:       .attr("index", i) .on("click", function() {
                            console.log(d3.select(this).attr("index"));

                        }

Comment: As I said above, you don't need to add the index as an attribute if you want to access it directly (see my answer, the `click` event in particular). Alternatively, if you want to have control over the "index", I recommend including it in the dataobject (say, a unique index from a db). But that's up to you. Good luck.